# How to go about splitting strings with multiple splitter values

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have a string of the following format:

```
0Days0hours51Minutes32Seconds
```

What I would like to do is split that into the 4 numerical values for

```
days,hours,minutes,seconds
```

So the values I would need back are 0, 0, 51, 32.

Are there any better ways of doing this the usual `string.Split(...)` method?

Ideally if there is a split by letters, so that only the numerical values remain.

Comment: use a regex to pull out the numbers

Comment: why not use Regular expressions ?

Comment: `regex.matches` on digit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string input = "0Days0hours51Minutes32Seconds";
var nums = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+").Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value))
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, regex. I knew I've used it in the past I just couldn't recall. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `String.Split(...)` you could use `Regex.Match(string,@"\d+")` to retrieve only the numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

```
var numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the numbers and don't care about the rest of the string, you can use:

```
string input = "0Days0hours51Minutes32Seconds";
var numbers = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+")
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value));
```

However, if you want to validate the string conforms to the expected format, you could use a more comprehensive pattern.

```
string input = "0Days0hours51Minutes32Seconds";
var match = Regex.Match(
    input,
    "^(\d+)Days(\d+)hours(\d+)Minutes(\d+)Seconds$");

var days = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
var hours = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
var minutes = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);
var seconds = int.Parse(match.Groups[4].Value);
```

I would also suggest you put these values into a useful structure like `TimeSpan`:

```
var timespan = new TimeSpan(days, hours, minutes, seconds);
```